# Preview info on mouse over on an image

Tags: 7, tooltips

How can I get the effect like on StackExchange where user information is displayed when you hover over their avatar?

I have a site that only has images on the front page, and would like the user to be able to get some information about the image before they click through.

I am using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use [qTip](http://drupal.org/project/qtip)

> qTips are stylish tooltips that can be configured and styled (more to
>   come in later releases) to fit nearly any website's design.

Comment: how can we use qTip module to display image's alt text on hover?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something the [Popup](http://drupal.org/project/popup) suite should be able to help you with.

> The popup suite allows builders to popup tooltip-like text, nodes, blocks, menus, forms, views and php-generated content.

I can't help much more I'm afraid as I've not used it, however I'd imagine you should just be able to create a block [View](http://www.drupal.org/project/views) containing user information and then expose this block as a popup when you hover/click on the username or user picture.

Comment: I will try to rephrase my question.  I have a website that uses views to strip out all other details and present logos on the home page and when one clicks on the logos the logo opens a full page.  i would like to display a short description as tooltip from one field (which should be hidden) and i would like it to appear like what is appearing  on some user icons or avatars on this site on mouse over.  I have tried popups and qtip but i am not able to get the effect, what am i missin